# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation not working in onCreate() method

Tags: android, geolocation, oncreate, fusedlocationproviderapi

Here is my code that uses the same method - once during `onCreate()` in my `MainActivity` and once after user clicks a button

```
// Below code not working during onCreate
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient. From Google API demo code
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    startLocationOnScreen.setText(getCurrentLocationViaPhoneLocation());

// Surprisingly same method works if it's called after a button press!

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                           startLocationOnScreen.setText(getCurrentLocationViaPhoneLocation());
```

So why would this be? I basically want to get user's current location when the app is loaded, not force user to press a button to get the same.

Implementation of `getCurrentLocationViaPhoneLocation()` Method -- (mostly taken from Google API docs)

```
protected String getCurrentLocationViaPhoneLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return "Error - location services not available!";
    }
    startLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (startLocation != null) {
        Log.e("We are at ", String.valueOf(startLocation.getLatitude()));
        Log.e("We are at ", String.valueOf(startLocation.getLongitude()));

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(startLocation.getLatitude(), startLocation.getLongitude(), 1);

            if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {


                currentCity = addressList.get(0).getLocality();


                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }

                return (sb.toString());

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    return ("Error - current location unavailable!");
}
```

**Edit:** I get: `Error - current location unavailable!` during `onCreate()` which means that `startLocation==null` when the method is called during `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the GoogleApiClient is not yet connected by the time you call the method the first time (i.e. during `onCreate`).

You already call the `addConnectionCallbacks` method of the Builder. Therefore you should have implemented the `onConnected(Bundle)` method of `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` in your Activity. Call the `getCurrentLocationViaPhoneLocation` method here instead of in the onCreated, then you can be sure the GoogleApiClient is properly connected.

If the `onConnected` method is not called, try to add `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` after creating the instance in your onCreate.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome, that was the problem, making the getCurrentLocationViaPhoneLocation call within the onConnected(Bundle) method solved the problem. Thank you so much!